# expl3/xparse: expansion, comparing tokens and xparse-defined macros

Tags: expl3, xparse

What is the correct (preferred?) way to do comparisons of whether a particular token---in my examples, it's typically a single character, but it could be something like `\mathcal{A}` or `\mathbf{b}` and the like---against a macro defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` and friends?

Here are some examples, each of which should give me a document consisting entirely of the word 'YES' if it works as desired and 'NO' if it did not. The comparison in the examples is whether `\foo` expands to the letter "n" when the comparison is performed.

Example 1 (does not work):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{}{n}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_if_eq:NnTF \foo {n}
{ YES }
{ NO }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

(note that the ExplSyntaxOn part inside `\begin{document}...\end{document}` is not something I would normally do; it's only there for the purposes of making a minimal example).

Example 2 (works):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newcommand*{\foo}{n}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_if_eq:NnTF \foo {n}
{ YES }
{ NO }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

I have tried variations, including defining `\foo` with `\cs_new:Npn` or `\cs_new_protected:Npn` and variations, and those work if I do this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \foo {n}
%\cs_new_protected:Npn \foo {n} % this works, too
\tl_new:N \l__foo_tl
\tl_set:NV \l__foo_tl \foo
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_if_eq:NnTF \l__foo_tl {n}
{ YES }
{ NO }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

However, I cannot come up with variations that make it work when `\foo` is defined with either `\NewDocumentCommand` or `NewExpandableDocumentCommand`.

I am certain I'm doing something wrong with the `\tl_if_eq` comparison, and I also know the problem traces back to how things are expanded, but I'm not certain what the "right" way to do this is for a command that is defined by `\NewDocumentCommand`.

Comment: 'Do not do this' - or at least explain why you need to do it in the first place

Comment: Also, don't use `minimal` for MWEs, use `article`, because `minimal` is not a proper class for actual use.

Comment: For NewExpandableDocumentCommand it's easy just use an `e` variant to expand before comparison, for NewDocumentCommand then not comparing is really the best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`  is for "document shortcuts" that expand to whatever the definition is, so here you can expand before comparing:

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\foo{}{n}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_if_eq:enTF {\foo} {n}
{ YES }
{ NO }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

However `\NewDocumentCommand` makes a new command and the fact that its definition is `n` is more or less intentionally considered an implementation detail. You would have to drop to ltcmd/xparse internals to extract the inner definition (which is not impossible, one could look at `\ShowCommand` which does exactly that)

Comment: Your example did not work, but I was able to get it working using `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnTF { enTF }`; does that indicate that my L3 kernel is out of date?

Comment: yes, we've been adding more `e` variants by default in recent releases. specifically my log shows `L3 programming layer <2023-10-10>` @karlh but adding the variant as you show is fine for older releases.

Comment: I think this is ultimately the solution I desired, though `tl_if_eq:xnTF` has the side effect that if a user actually passed `\foo` as the argument in place of `n`, it fails; setting up `tl_if_eq:xxTF` seems to work as desired in this case. Thank you!

Comment: @karlh sure you could use xx  (or ee) if you want to expand both arguments